# ActiveStorage download File / IO from attachment object on S3 service?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

After the file is uploaded, I want to analyze and immediately process.

I'm currently attaching then processing each:

```
current_account.archives.attach(archive_params)
current_account.archives.each do |archive|
  Job.enqueue(AccountArchiveImportJob.new(current_account.id, archive.id))
end
```

In the job i'm opening the CSV and parsing junk

```
attachment = Account.find(account_id).archives.where(id: archive_id).first

CSV.parse(attachment.download) do |row|
  do_stuff_with_the_row(row)
end
```

I would like to do something like:

```
CSV.foreach(attachment.open) do |row|
  do_stuff_with_the_row(row)
end
```

I cannot find documentation that allows converting the attachment back into a FILE

Comment: AFAIK activestorage does not keep the io or blob around. it tries to upload that stuff and only store the metadata. so if you would like to process the file in the same context where it's loaded, you will need to keep track of it yourself.

Answer (score 3):

At least from Rails 6.0 rc1:

```rb
model.attachment_changes['attachment_name'].attachable
```

will give you IO of the original TmpFile **BEFORE** it is uploaded.

Comment: I had to do `attachment_changes['attachment_name'].attachable[:io]` but it worked great!

Answer (score 1):

Rails-6 we will get a `download` method that will yield a file but you can get this very easily!

[Add this `downloader.rb` file as an initializer](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a6d80e164f2f5566472370a84ab7cd98736666c4/activestorage/lib/active_storage/downloader.rb)

Then given this model

```
class Business < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :csvfile
end
```

you can do

```
ActiveStorage::Downloader.new(csvfile).download_blob_to_tempfile do |file|
  CSV.foreach(file.path, {headers: true}) do |row|
    do_something_with_each_row(row.to_h)
  end
end
```

**EDIT**: not sure why this took me to so long to find `service_url`.  Way more simple, but has been [noted that `service_url` should not be shown to users](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html#method-i-service_url)

```
open(csvfile.service_url)
```

Comment: I used with `downloader.rb` to attached (uploaded) file to email. 

[Rails 5.2 Official guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/active_storage_overview.html#downloading-files) described similar way (use separate model and include module) to download and process file.

Answer (score 0):

From Rails 5.2 official guide

```rb
class VirusScanner
  include ActiveStorage::Downloading

  attr_reader :blob

  def initialize(blob)
    @blob = blob
  end

  def scan
    download_blob_to_tempfile do |file|
      system 'scan_virus', file.path
    end
  end
end
```

So you can do

```rb
  include ActiveStorage::Downloading

  attr_reader :blob

  def initialize(blob)
    @blob = blob
  end

  def perform
    download_blob_to_tempfile do |file|
      CSV.foreach(file.path, {headers: true}) do |row|
        do_something_with_each_row(row.to_h)
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get the file path from the attachment, and then open the file.

```
path = ActiveStorage::Blob.service.send(:path_for, attachment.key)
File.open(path) do |file|
    #...
end
```

Comment: I'm seeing an error with this `undefined method path_for for #<ActiveStorage::Service::S3Service:0x007f43cc9bd180>`

Comment: Oh, I did not realize you are using Amazon S3. I assumed you are saving files locally. Looks like my answer won't work for you.